In AWS API Gateway, can method level limits for a specific end point exceed stage level limit?
I'm working with AWS API Gateway and I need to configure throttle limits for a specific method that exceed the stage-level limits.
Here’s the scenario:
Stage-level throttle limits: rate: 10 requests per second, Burst: 20 requests
Method-level throttle limits: rate: 20 requests per second, Burst: 30 requests
If I configure the method-level throttle limits as shown, what will be the actual effective limits for that method? Will the method-level limits override the stage-level limits, or is there some interaction between them that affects the final throttle behavior?
I want to ensure that the method can handle up to 20 requests per second with a Burst of 30 requests, even though the stage-level limits are lower. Can someone clarify how these settings will interact and what the final throttle limits for the method will be?

This documentation says:

API Gateway applies your throttling-related settings in the following
order:
1. Per-client or per-method throttling limits that you set for an API stage in a usage plan
2. Per-method throttling limits that you set for an API stage
3. Account-level throttling per Region
4. AWS Regional throttling


So since it applies checks "in order," it means that the request must be allowed (below the throttle limit) at each point as it get checked.

Just to confirm, does this mean that method-level limits can never exceed the stage-level throttle limits?

I understand it to mean that it will check the first limit (#1).  If the request is below the limit, then it checks the 2nd limit (#2).  If the request is below the limit is continues to #3 and then on the #4.  Those limits set in each are independent, but it does mean that the most restrictive limit will be the one that ultimately applies.  So even if an earlier check allows a higher limit, a subsequent check with a lower limit could cause throttling.
